# neo4j turn paths into subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have the following graph

```
       Z
  /         \ 
 /           \  
A -> B -> C -> D
 \          /
  -> X -> Y
```

I compute the paths

```
match p=((:A)-[*]->[:D])
return p
```

This will return three paths (rows): AZD, ABCD and AXYD

But I would like to return a subgraph that contains all the paths between A and D. so the result should be a subgraph. My understanding is that the only format for a subgraph return is nodes and relationships. So a query like below

```
// query logic
return nodes, relationships
```

What should I write in the query logic? NOTE:

1. this is not the entire graph, there are other subgraphs in my graph, so returning the entire graph does not work
2. A and D are just node types here, there will be many type A and type D nodes and there will be one or multiple paths between each A and D node pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to retrieve the unique set of nodes and relationships is using apoc

```
MATCH p=((:A)-[*]->(:D))    
RETURN apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(nodes(p))
            )
       ) AS nodes,
       apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(relationships(p))
            )
       ) AS relationships
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized my problem was more complicated than this. Could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73672305/neo4j-merge-paths-into-subgraphs-based-on-common-elements?

Comment: Do you want to take a crack at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291472/how-to-write-cypher-to-perform-traversal-that-only-returns-unique-paths-and-base?noredirect=1#comment131188294_74291472