# generate subgraphs from special match rules

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have the following graph:

```
(a1:A) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (d1:D)
   \                          /
     - -> (x1:X) - --> (y1:Y)

(a2:A) -> (b2:B) -> (c2:C) -> (d2:D)

(a3:A) -> (x3:X) -> (y3:Y) -> (d3:D)
```

The actual graph also contains other relationships between node label A and D. But I am only interested in these relationships between A and D. So I have to force some rules on the path. see query below

```
match p1=((:A)-->(:B)-->(:C)->(:D))
return p1

match p2=((:A)-->(:X)-->(:Y)->(:D))
return p2
```

This will return me four rows

```
a1-b1-c1-d1
a1-x1-y1-d1
a2-b2-c2-d2
a3-x3-y3-d3
```

But I would like to return an array of subgraphs and merge paths based on the common node attribute D.name. I.e., d1, d2, d3 are differentiated by their node attribute called "name". So the output I would like to have is

```
   // query logic
   // return subgraphs, each subgraph is a row. each subgraph contains the unique node and relationships  from A to D. If there are multiple paths to the same D, then merge these paths to the same subgraph
```

More concretely, the return of the above example becomes

```
   row1: nodes(a1, b1, c1, d1, x1, y1), relationships(a1, b1, c1, d1, x1, y1)
   row2: nodes(a2, b2, c2, d2), relationships(a2, b2, c2, d2)
   row3: nodes(a3, x3, y3, d3), relationships(a3, x3, y3, d3)
```

What would be the query?

UPDATE:
Test graph

```
merge (a1:A{name: 'a1'})
merge (b1:B{name: 'b1'})
merge (c1:C{name: 'c1'})
merge (d1:D{name: 'd1'})
merge (x1:X{name: 'x1'})
merge (y1:Y{name: 'y1'})

merge (a2:A{name: 'a2'})
merge (b2:B{name: 'b2'})
merge (c2:C{name: 'c2'})
merge (d2:D{name: 'd2'})

merge (a3:A{name: 'a3'})
merge (x3:X{name: 'x3'})
merge (y3:Y{name: 'y3'})
merge (d3:D{name: 'd3'})

merge(a1)-[:TESTS]->(b1)
merge(b1)-[:TESTS]->(c1)
merge(c1)-[:TESTS]->(d1)
merge(a1)-[:TESTS]->(x1)
merge(x1)-[:TESTS]->(y1)
merge(y1)-[:TESTS]->(d1)

merge(a2)-[:TESTS]->(b2)
merge(b2)-[:TESTS]->(c2)
merge(c2)-[:TESTS]->(d2)

merge(a3)-[:TESTS]->(x3)
merge(x3)-[:TESTS]->(y3)
merge(y3)-[:TESTS]->(d3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that not just the `:D` nodes are different, but also the `:A` nodes. But, assuming that you want group by `d.name`, I guess this does it.

```
MATCH p=((:A)-[*]->(d:D))    
RETURN d.name AS dName,
       apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(nodes(p))
            )
       ) AS nodes,
apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(relationships(p))
            )
       ) AS relationships
```

In case you want to filter for specific paths, you can do something like:

```
MATCH (a:A), (d:D)
OPTIONAL MATCH p1=((a)-->(:B)-->(:C)-->(d))
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=((a)-->(:X)-->(:Y)-->(d))

WITH d.name AS dName,
       apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(COALESCE(nodes(p1),[]) + COALESCE(nodes(p2),[]))
            )
       ) AS nodes,
apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(COALESCE(relationships(p1),[]) + COALESCE(relationships(p2),[]))
            )
       ) AS relationships
WHERE nodes <> []

RETURN nodes, relationships
```

Comment: Actually this fits into mostly what I need. But what about doing this and at the same time forcing the two matching rules? Cause I need two specific patterns for the paths from A to D and specially I am merging based on d.name across two path matching rules.

Comment: I.e., p=((:A)-[*]->(d:D)) will produce some paths that i dont want

Comment: @drdot extended the answer

Comment: Getting closer..but there is one more issue: this requires both p1 and p2 have matches. If you look at the expected output in the post, I am expecting 3 rows based on the distinct d.name. i.e., the result should include path matching p1 or p2 or (p1 + p2 but dedup nodes, relationship in this case)

Comment: you can add OPTIONAL , see above

Comment: Hmm, i was expecting that would work...but it generate empty results for nodes and relationship for everything else except the d.name="d1" node. You can test using the test graph I updated above.

Comment: WHERE nodes <> []   would fix that I guess plus COALESCE()

Comment: The program just got upgraded again. Hope you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73677103/get-different-decorating-nodes-from-a-complex-subgraph-relationship