# Get different decorating nodes from a complex subgraph relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have the following graph:

```
                    (r1:R)  (r11:R)
                      |     /
                    (p1:P)
                       |
(a1:A) -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (d1:D)
   \                          /
     - -> (x1:X) - --> (y1:Y)
            |
          (p11:P)
            |
          (r111:R)


                    (r2:R)
                      |
                    (p2:P)
                      |
(a2:A) -> (b2:B) -> (c2:C) -> (d2:D)


(a3:A) -> (x3:X) -> (y3:Y) -> (d3:D)
            |
          (p3:P)
            |
          (r3:R)
```

and I can use this query to get path based on specific rules and merge paths based on the D node attribute name into subgraphs

```
MATCH (a:A), (d:D)
OPTIONAL MATCH p1=((a)-->(:B)-->(:C)-->(d))
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=((a)-->(:X)-->(:Y)-->(d))

WITH d.name AS dName,
       apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(COALESCE(nodes(p1),[]) + COALESCE(nodes(p2),[]))
            )
       ) AS nodes,
apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(COALESCE(relationships(p1),[]) + COALESCE(relationships(p2),[]))
            )
       ) AS relationships
WHERE nodes <> []

RETURN nodes, relationships
```

But notice for C and X nodes, these are decorating nodes P and R. There is always a P node decorating C node and there can be at least one R nodes decorating P nodes.

Now for my desirable query return, for each node, relationships, i would also like to get an array of json object of P, R and the nodes that P is decorating. More concretely, the return of the above graph becomes

```
   row1: nodes(a1, b1, c1, d1, x1, y1), relationships(a1, b1, c1, d1, x1, y1), [{SRC:c1, P: p1, R:[r1, r11]}, {SRC:x1, P:p11, R:[r111]}]
   row2: nodes(a2, b2, c2, d2), relationships(a2, b2, c2, d2), [{SRC:c2, P:p2, R:[r2]}]
   row3: nodes(a3, x3, y3, d3), relationships(a3, x3, y3, d3), [{SRC:x3, P:p3, R:[r3]}]
```

How should I change my query? NOTE: for the SRC,P,R structure, I am open for other formats that can help the query to be easier to construct, but it needs to be able to identity the same relationships between SRC,P,R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (a:A), (d:D)
OPTIONAL MATCH p1=((a)-->(:B)-->(:C)-->(d))
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=((a)-->(:X)-->(:Y)-->(d))

WITH d.name AS dName,
       apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(COALESCE(nodes(p1),[]) + COALESCE(nodes(p2),[]))
            )
       ) AS nodes,
apoc.coll.toSet(
            apoc.coll.flatten(
                 COLLECT(COALESCE(relationships(p1),[]) + COALESCE(relationships(p2),[]))
            )
       ) AS relationships
WHERE nodes <> []
WITH nodes, relationships,
     [src IN nodes WHERE src:X OR src:C |
              {
                SRC: src,
                P: HEAD([(src)--(p:P) | p]),
                R: [(src)--(p:P)--(r:R) | r]
              }
     ] AS srcs

RETURN nodes, relationships, srcs
```

Comment: Realized another case I need to improve on, could you take a look? Note the graph changed a little bit .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73685302/collect-decorating-nodes-based-on-if-else-conditions