# How to write cypher to perform traversal that only returns unique paths and based on scores

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph

```
(a1:A {name: 'a1', s:1})     ->                          -> (a20001:A {name: 'a20001', s:11})
(a2:A {name: 'a2', s:10})    ->(b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B)-> (a20002:A {name: 'a20002', s:123})
(a10000:A {name: 'a10000', s:30})->                      -> (a30000:A {name: 'a30000', s:1})
```

On the left, there are N number of type A nodes that connect to the same type B node on the left. On the right, there are M number of type A nodes that connect to another type B node on the right. Each type A node has an attribute called `s` which indicates a score.

If I do a simple query like this

```
match p=((a1:A)--(b1:B)--(:C)--(b2:B)--(a2:A))
where a1 <> a2 and b1 <> b2
return p
```

I will get N*M number of paths, i.e., all the paths from each left side type A node to right side type A node.

However, I want to get the paths from type A node on the left to type A node on the right using a special traversal rule:

Find the highest score node A on the left and find the highest score node A on the right, find the paths between these two. Then find the second highest score node A on the left and find the second highest score node A on the right and find the paths between these two. Other paths follows the same logic. If N < M, then the loop left side back from the highest score until all the right side node has been traversed with a path, i.e., produce N paths. If N > M, then stop path search when we have M paths. So in the above example, it will produce the following paths

```
(a10000:A {name:'a10000',s:30})-> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (a20002:A {name:'a20002',s:123})
(a2:A {name:'a2',s:10})    -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (a20001:A {name:'a20001',s:11})
(a1:A {name:'a1',s:1})     -> (b1:B) -> (c1:C) -> (b2:B) -> (a30000:A {name:'a30000',s:1})
```

Can I achieve this by cypher? I can tweak the graph to add metadata to make the cypher queries easier if needed.

Comment: How do you differentiate between A nodes on the left and on the right?

Comment: @TomažBratanič thank you for the Q. I updated the post. added the name attribute for node to differentiate.